# Laravel Left join Query explanation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, left-join

I have the following tables:

Users, Studies, Study_User and Questions. The relationships are:

Many-to-Many between Users and Studies via study_user.

Studies One-to-Many Questions

Can someone please explain to me what does this query do?
Does it bring all the Questions that belongs to studies which a certain user is part of?

```
public function questions(){
  $builder = Question::
                 groupBy('questions.id');

        $builder = $builder
            ->leftjoin('studies', 'studies.id', '=', 'questions.study_id')
            ->leftjoin('study_users', 'studies.id', '=', 'study_users.study_id')

            ->where('study_users.user_id', '=', $this->id)

            ->where('studies.starts_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->where('studies.ends_at', '>=', Carbon::now())

            ->select('questions.*');
      return $builder;
}
```

That function is then called as

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->questions()->get();
```

Ok and now the other question would be:

Assume that we add another table called Modules where : Studies one-to-many Modules and then Modules one-to-many Questions. So that we break the direct relationship between Studies and Questions. How the query should change to get the same results?

Comment: it returns the user's questions that now is between his studies start_at  and end_at

Comment: Thanks. Ok, Assume that we add another table called Modules where : Studies one-to-many Modules and then Modules one-to-many Studies. So that we 
break the direct relationship between Studies and Questions. How the query should change to get the same results?

Comment: Do you have all the necessary relationships set up in your Eloquent models?

Comment: Yes, they are all setup.

Comment: @TsaiKoga You're absolutely right. I'm not sure why I thought that (**facepalm)

Comment: @marmahan Since you have the relationships set up then you should be able to potentially simplify your query using `whereHas()`. It will mean the you won't need to manually join the tables on and you won't have to use a group by statement either.

Comment: @Rwd thanks. I understand now what the query does, how can I get the same results if we add another table called Modules where : Studies one-to-many Modules and then Modules one-to-many Studies. So that we break the direct relationship between Studies and Questions. How should i change the query to get the same results?

Comment: "Studies one-to-many Modules and then Modules one-to-many Studies"?? Is this a typo?

Comment: "Studies one-to-many Modules and then Modules one-to-many Questions. Yep, typo

Comment: It should just be a case of adding an extra join for the modules table.

Comment: @Rwd Could you please write it as a solution?

Comment: @Rwd as in writing the query I mean

Comment: `->leftJoin('modules', 'studies.module_id', 'modules.id')`

Comment: Thanks. so that would be the very first thing to add?